# Warning: implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 71

Tags: arguments, warnings, implode

i try to convert csv file to tsv using below code.

in my csv the first word has no value. 
when i run the code it generate tsv file correctly , but it gives above error. please help

Thanks

```
$myfile = "file path"; 
function convert($filename) 
{
if(@$fh_in = fopen("{$filename}.csv","r")) 
{
$fh_out = fopen("{$filename}.tsv","a"); 

while(!feof($fh_in))
{
$line = array();
$line = fgetcsv($fh_in,1024);
fwrite($fh_out,implode("\t",$line)."\n"); 
}

fclose($fh_in);
fclose($fh_out);

}
else { 
echo "File doesn’t exist\n";
return false;
}
echo "Conversion completed!\n";
return true; 
}
convert($myfile);
```

Comment: Might be doing that on a blank line

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/implode), implode can be

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
string implode ( array $pieces )
```

So in your case if `$line` is empty then it will execute with second prototype and consider `\n` as $pieces which is wrong. So check for value in `$line` before calling implode

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is the question i have. i want to convert CSV to tsv and in there i want to create a program to work with empty values.  also \n is out side the brackets. so is is consider \n as a value here.